# bootstrap tooltip does not work on second table when a page has multiple tables

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

i am trying to get the bootstrap tooltip to work on multiple tables on a single web page. currently, i can see the bootstrap tooltip work on one table but not the second table. both my tables have the data-toggle="tooltip" and title attributes.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({container: 'body'});   
});
```

here is a snippet of the td element

```
<td data-toggle="tooltip" title="testing">testing-cell</td>
```

Comment: When you say not working, are you getting an error?

Comment: sorry, let me clarify. the second table does not give the bootstrap style tooltips.

Comment: Please show your markup too, there should be nothing wrong with the approach above ...

Comment: i should of mentioned i am also using angularjs. i just tried a sample page without angular, the tooltips is working. is using angularjs causing an issue?